# Readonly /var/lib/gdm3/.local/

Tags: 18.04, scanner, gdm

I've some odd behaviours with screen (nvidia) and scanner (Epson V330), my syslog shows from time to time this message

```
Oct 25 19:52:30 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 gsd-color[5655]: failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/edid-c16ba004ffc69e8889a4dfc31cb00abb.icc”: Permission denied
Oct 25 19:52:32 lrkwz-Precision-M4500 gsd-color[5655]: message repeated 3 times: [ failed to set screen _ICC_PROFILE: Failed to open file “/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/edid-c16ba004ffc69e8889a4dfc31cb00abb.icc”: Permission denied]
```

Why is `/var/lib/gdm3/.local` read-only?

```
$ sudo ls -l /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/edid-c16ba004ffc69e8889a4dfc31cb00abb.icc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gdm gdm 1420 set  1 00:05 /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/edid-c16ba004ffc69e8889a4dfc31cb00abb.icc
```

The complete tree is:

```
$ sudo ls -la /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/edid-c16ba004ffc69e8889a4dfc31cb00abb.icc /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/ /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/ /var/lib/gdm3/.local/ /var/lib/gdm3/ /var/lib/                   
-rw-rw-r--  1 gdm  gdm  1420 set  1 00:05 /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/edid-c16ba004ffc69e8889a4dfc31cb00abb.icc

/var/lib/:
total 272
drwxr-xr-x 68 root          root          4096 ott 27 23:33 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:05 AccountsService
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 mag  1  2013 acpi-support
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 28 18:36 alsa
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 ott 29 10:57 app-info
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 set 14 11:19 apport
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 ott 28 11:23 apt
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:10 aspell
drwxr-xr-x  2 avahi-autoipd avahi-autoipd 4096 lug 25 05:08 avahi-autoipd
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 ago 31 23:41 bluetooth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 mag 25 10:47 boltd
drwxr-xr-x  4 colord        colord        4096 set  1 00:05 colord
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 mag  5 08:41 command-not-found
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 set  1 00:05 dbus
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 apr 16  2018 dhcp
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:08 dictionaries-common
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 set 14 14:13 dkms
drwx--x--x 15 root          root          4096 ott 29 10:57 docker
drwxr-xr-x  7 root          root          4096 ott 28 11:23 dpkg
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:06 emacsen-common
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 set  1 00:06 fwupd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 feb 14  2018 fwupdate
drwxr-xr-x  5 root          root          4096 set  1 00:35 gconf
drwxr-xr-x  6 gdm           gdm           4096 ott 29 10:57 gdm3
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 ott 19 15:16 gems
drwxr-xr-x  3 geoclue       geoclue       4096 set  1 00:05 geoclue
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:06 ghostscript
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 mag 31 19:50 git
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 set 11 17:09 hp
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 25 09:45 initramfs-tools
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 12 12:44 iscan
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 12 12:44 iscan-data
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:06 ispell
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:07 libxml-sax-perl
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:10 locales
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 30 00:07 logrotate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:08 man-db
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 apr 24  2018 misc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 30 00:08 mlocate
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 30 06:46 NetworkManager
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 25 09:45 os-prober
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 30 09:52 PackageKit
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:08 pam
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 set  1 00:05 plymouth
drwx------  3 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:04 polkit-1
drwx------  3 root          root          4096 set  1 00:05 private
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 set  1 11:41 python
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 ott 27 23:36 samba
drwxr-xr-x 19 root          root          4096 ott 30 06:32 snapd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 feb 20  2018 snmp
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:04 sudo
drwxr-xr-x  9 root          root          4096 set 22 11:49 systemd
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 set  1 00:00 ubiquity
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 set  1 00:05 ubuntu-drivers-common
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 22 00:14 ubuntu-release-upgrader
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 ott 27 23:34 ucf
drwx------  2 root          root          4096 ott 29 09:58 udisks2
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 set  1 00:15 update-manager
drwxr-xr-x  4 root          root          4096 ott 30 09:24 update-notifier
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 29 10:07 upower
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 ott 25 22:00 ureadahead
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 mar  6  2018 usb_modeswitch
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:05 usbutils
drwxr-xr-x  3 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:04 vim
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 29 10:57 whoopsie
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 lug 25 05:09 xfonts
drwxr-xr-x  2 root          root          4096 ott 28 11:22 xkb

/var/lib/gdm3/:
total 96
drwxr-xr-x  6 gdm  gdm   4096 ott 29 10:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 68 root root  4096 ott 27 23:33 ..
drwxr-xr-x  7 gdm  gdm   4096 set  1 12:09 .cache
drwxr-xr-x  7 gdm  gdm   4096 set  5 11:49 .config
drwx------  3 gdm  gdm   4096 set  1 00:05 .gnupg
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  4339 ott 25 20:35 greeter-dconf-defaults
-rw-------  1 gdm  gdm  57810 ott 29 10:57 .ICEauthority
drwx------  3 gdm  gdm   4096 set  1 00:05 .local

/var/lib/gdm3/.local/:
total 12
drwx------ 3 gdm gdm 4096 set  1 00:05 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 gdm gdm 4096 ott 29 10:57 ..
drwx------ 8 gdm gdm 4096 set 25 23:50 share

/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/:
total 36
drwx------ 8 gdm gdm 4096 set 25 23:50  .
drwx------ 3 gdm gdm 4096 set  1 00:05  ..
drwx------ 2 gdm gdm 4096 set  1 00:05  gnome-shell
drwxrwxr-x 2 gdm gdm 4096 set  1 00:05  ibus-table
drwxrwxr-x 2 gdm gdm 4096 set 25 23:50  icc
drwx------ 2 gdm gdm 4096 set  1 00:05  keyrings
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gdm gdm  100 set  1 00:05 'session_migration-(null)'
drwx------ 2 gdm gdm 4096 set  1 00:05  sounds
drwx------ 2 gdm gdm 4096 ott  2 21:49  xorg

/var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/:
total 16
drwxrwxr-x 2 gdm gdm 4096 set 25 23:50 .
drwx------ 8 gdm gdm 4096 set 25 23:50 ..
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gdm gdm 1420 set  1 00:05 edid-c16ba004ffc69e8889a4dfc31cb00abb.icc
-rw-rw-r-- 1 gdm gdm 1480 set 25 23:50 edid-d5eee630e5f2d664cb0b2b2b513fc95a.icc
```

Comment: permissions denied is not perse read only. it could also be that the file does not exist cuz one of the directories leading up to the file does not exist. can you add "ls -l"  for all the directories into the question?

Comment: @Rinzwind I edited the question adding `sudo ls -l`

Comment: Looks like only user gdm is allowed inside .local. 2 possible things to look into gsd-color needs to be told to use gdm as a user. Or you could do a `sudo chmod 755 /var/lib/gdm3/.local/share/icc/*icc` but that might be temporary ;)